# Condense the expression $3\log_7v+6\log_7w-\frac{\log_7u}{3}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

I am to condense the expression $3\log_7v+6log_7w-\frac{\log_7u}{3}$. The solution is provided as $\log_7(\frac{v^3w^6}{\sqrt[3]{u}})$

I can see how the numerator was arrived at using the properties of logs but I cannot see how the denominator is obtained?

As far as I got:

$log_7(\frac{v^3w^6}{\frac{\log_7u}{3}})$

In baby steps, how can I get my denominator from $\frac{\log_7u}{3}$ to $\sqrt[3]{u}$

Comment: $$\begin{align}3\log_7v+6\log_7w-\frac{\log_7u}{3}
=\log_7v^3+\log_7w^6-\log_7u^{\frac 13}
=\log_7\left(\frac{v^3w^6}{\sqrt[3]{u}}\right)\end{align}$$

Comment: Use ```\log_a```. Consider $log_ax$ vs. $\log_ax$. Also, use ```$$…$$``` for big expressions (they will format in a new line).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$3\log_7v+6\log_7w-\frac{\log_7u}{3} = \log_7v^3 + \log_7w^6 - \log_7u^{1/3} = \log_7(\frac {v^3w^6}{u^{1/3}}).$$

Is that clear now?

Comment: I edited the answer and fixed MathJax. See the edit to know more about formatting mathematical equations (use double dollars for big lines).

Comment: What I don't follow here is how the $log_7u$ is replaced with just $u$. The $log_7$ part has been removed somehow and I don't follow that. How does $-log_7u^{1/3}$ become $\sqrt[3]{u}$?

Comment: That is absolutely false. Maybe some typo.

Comment: Ah. This textbook has had a few errors in the solutions before. Let me share the link for my sanity: The question is #35 [here](https://openstax.org/books/algebra-and-trigonometry/pages/6-review-exercises) and the solution is near the bottom [here](https://openstax.org/books/algebra-and-trigonometry/pages/chapter-6), 'review excercises #35'

Comment: The answer is correct.